# How to develop phonegap plugin for windows phone to play audio file form web server?

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working on phone gap app for Windows Phone. I want to play audio file from server on phone.

How should I build phonegap plugin for Windows Phone for playing audio file?

Comment: try this without plugin http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/streaming-audio-and-video-with-html-5

Comment: I want to write code to play audio in native(c#) & passing url through phonegap